Why does WhatsApp Flow template dropdown show static values despite dynamic data integration?
I created WhatsApp Flows using templates, it only contains one dropdown, here the user needs to select the person in the dropdown, it's works if I use this JSON from Flow Builder, but if I change this to a dynamic value, nothing changes in it's previewing the static Value(the data come with while creating the template )
What went wrong with the code? how can I modify the JSON and Apply Custom Data?
,

flow JSON

   {
          "version": "3.1",
          "screens": [
            {
              "id": "QUESTION_ONE",
              "title": "Your form",
              "data": {},
              "terminal": true,
              "layout": {
                "type": "SingleColumnLayout",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "type": "Form",
                    "name": "flow_path",
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "type": "Dropdown",
                        "label": "Person",
                        "required": true,
                        "name": "Dropdown_07042a",
                        "data-source": [
                          {
                            "id": "0_Option_1",
                            "title": "Option 1"
                          },
                          {
                            "id": "1_Option_2",
                            "title": "Option 2"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "type": "Footer",
                        "label": "Continue",
                        "on-click-action": {
                          "name": "complete",
                          "payload": {
                            "screen_0_Dropdown_0": "${form.Dropdown_07042a}"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }


modified(dynamic value) JSON with API Request

{
    "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
    "recipient_type": "individual",
    "to": "{{Recipient-Phone-Number}}",
    "type": "template",
    "template": {
        "name": "dynamic_drop_down",
        "language": {
            "code": "en_US"
        },
        "components": [
            {
                "type": "button",
                "sub_type": "flow",
                "index": "0",
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "type": "action",
                        "action": {
                            "flow_token": "FLOW_TOKEN",
                            "flow_action_data": {
                                "version": "3.1",
                                "screens": [
                                    {
                                        "id": "QUESTION_ONE",
                                        "title": "Your form",
                                        "data": {
                                            "all_burgers": {
                                                "type": "array",
                                                "items": {
                                                    "type": "object",
                                                    "properties": {
                                                        "id": {
                                                            "type": "string"
                                                        },
                                                        "title": {
                                                            "type": "string"
                                                        },
                                                        "description": {
                                                            "type": "string"
                                                        },
                                                        "metadata": {
                                                            "type": "string"
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "__example__": [
                                                    {
                                                        "id": "1",
                                                        "title": "Beef burger",
                                                        "description": "Beef, red onion relish, lettuce",
                                                        "metadata": "$9.99"
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "id": "2",
                                                        "title": "Chicken burger",
                                                        "description": "Grilled chicken breast, cheese, buffalo sause",
                                                        "metadata": "$10.99"
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "terminal": true,
                                        "layout": {
                                            "type": "SingleColumnLayout",
                                            "children": [
                                                {
                                                    "type": "Form",
                                                    "name": "flow_path",
                                                    "children": [
                                                        {
                                                            "type": "Dropdown",
                                                            "label": "Person",
                                                            "required": true,
                                                            "data-source": "${data.all_burgers}",
                                                            "on-select-action": {
                                                                "name": "data_exchange",
                                                                "payload": {
                                                                    "burger": "${form.burger}"
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        },
                                                        {
                                                            "type": "Footer",
                                                            "label": "Continue",
                                                            "on-click-action": {
                                                                "name": "complete",
                                                                "payload": {
                                                                    "screen_0_Dropdown_0": "${form.Dropdown_07042a}"
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}



but if I change this to a dynamic value, nothing changes in it's
previewing the static Value

What exactly do you change here?

did you select the "interactive preview" in the preview sections, that will start the data exchange with URL you provided.
If yes, are you getting API calls on your server, do you see any error?


Ankur, Thank you for your reply, I haven't gotten any error messages, whatever the value I change in the data, that is not getting applied to the flow template, do you have any working sample or any referrals

May be you can try some logging at your backend server to check what you are sending back to client or check network logs to see the API response at client, providing some of that info would be helpful.
Try use the Glitch example, here you can setup the backend server quickly, it has all the logs that would be helpful to debug.
Just fork(remix) the server, add your encryption key(don't add production version) and use the url in builder.
guide: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/flows/guides/implementingyourflowendpoint
server: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/whatsapp-flows-endpoint
